# Android Studio limitations?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, butterknife

Im having a quite big project with some modules.

On one of them declared as a library project i want to use Butterknife, Android Studio  does not compile the Code when written in butterknife Style:

```
@InjectView(R.id.webView)
private WebView webView;
```

I get the error **Attribute must be a constant**

Same compiles without any problem when im not using Butterknife

```
    webView = (WebView) getView().findViewById(R.id.webView);
```

I cleaned my caches and started the IDE again. No luck.

Interesting is that @InjectView works when using in non library project (their use the library project)

PS: I also try to compile directly in console, same problem.

Comment: R.id.webView probably isn't a constant in this case. Is it coming from an AAR library?

Comment: No, it's defined in a layout part of the library project i want to access it.

Comment: This probably has nothing to do with Android Studio. Have you tried to clean and rebuild your project? Most likely something went wrong when the `R` class was generated.

Comment: No, the R File is fine, project compiles when removing this. seems like the int field is not an final any longer. Those filed will be merged durring the dexing so that may be the issue. A bit das that you cant use butterknife for your own library projects